# Find an axiomatization for the lexicographic ordering of the cartesian product of the rationals

Tags: logic, model-theory

"Consider the following countably infinite structure $\mathcal{A}$. The underlying set of $\mathcal{A}$ is the rational plane $\mathbb{Q}\times\mathbb{Q}$ (i.e., ordered pairs of rationals). The language of $\mathcal{A}$ consists of two binary relations $<$ and $\sim$. The relation $<$ is defined on $\mathcal{A}$ by $(p_1, p_2) < (q_1, q_2)$ if $p_1<q_1$ or if $p_1 = q_1$ and $p_2 < q_2$ (that is, the lexicographic ordering of $\mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{Q}$). The relation $\sim$ on $A$ is an equivalence relation defined by $(p_1, p_2) \sim (q_1, q_2)$ iff $p_1 = q_1$. Thus the structure $\mathcal{A}$ may be though of as a "stack" of $\mathbb{Q}$ many copies of $\mathbb{Q}$, which each copy being a block of $\sim$.

1. Is $\mathcal{A}$ homogeneous, and if not, is it at least $\omega$-categorical?
2. Write down an axiomatization for the theory of $\mathcal{A}$; some list of sentences such that all models of these sentences are elementarily equivalent to $\mathcal{A}$. You may want to use your answers to Question 1 to prove the completeness of your axioms."

Here's what I have so far:

For Question 1, I think that $\mathcal{A}$ is $\omega$-categorical, as the Duplicator (or $\exists$loise) will always win the Ehrenfeucht-Fraisse game. I also think that $\mathcal{A}$ is homogeneous, as any isomorphism can be extended to an automorphism using the density of the lexicographic ordering of $\mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{Q}$. Are my thoughts correct?

For Question 2, here are the sentences I have so far:

- Reflexivity, symmetry and transitivity for $\sim$
- Transitivity and irreflexivity for $<$.
- There is no greatest element and there is no least element for $<$.
- Linearity of $<$ (that is, $\forall x \forall y: x < y \vee y < x \vee x = y$)
- Density of $<$ (that is, $(\forall x \forall z: x < z) \rightarrow (\exists y: x < y \wedge y < z)$).

Are there any sentences that I'm missing? Also, how would I go about using Question 1 to prove completeness?

Finally, if you need them, here are some definitions:

- A structure is $\mathcal{B}$ is homogeneous if any isomorphism between two finitely generated substructures of $\mathcal{B}$ extends to an automorphism of $\mathcal{B}$.
- A theory $T$ is $\omega$-categorical if every two countable models of $T$ are isomorphic.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your axioms are insufficient; they are satisfied by ($\mathbb Q,\lt,\sim)$ if $\lt$ is the usual ordering of rationals and $\sim$ is **any equivalence relation whatsoever**, unrelated to the ordering.

Comment: Suggested axioms: (1) $\lt$ is a linear ordering; (2) $\sim$ is an equivalence relation; (3) for any $x,$ the set $\{y:y\sim x\}$ is convex, densely ordered, and has no least or greatest element; (4) for any elements $x,y$ with $x\lt y$ and $x\not\sim y,$ there is an element $z$ such that $x\lt z\lt y$ and $x\not\sim z$ and $z\not\sim y;$ (5) for any element $x$ there is an element $y$ such that $y\lt x$ and $y\not\sim x;$ (6) for any element $x$ there is an element $y$ such that $x\lt y$ and $x\not\sim y.$

Comment: @bof I see, my mistake was not considering the two relations together. For (3), what do you mean by convex? I know the usual definition of a convex set (e.g. [this definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_set#In_vector_spaces)) but I don't see why convexity is needed.

Comment: I used the word "convex" loosely to make it all fit into a comment box. I call a subset $S$ of a linearly ordered set "convex" if $a,b\in S,a\lt x\lt b\implies x\in S.$ This is true in your structure $\mathcal A$ and does not follow from the other axioms. E.g., if the equivalence relation $\sim$ corresponds to a partition of $\mathbb Q$ into three or more subsets each of which is order-isomorphic to $\mathbb Q$ and dense in $\mathbb Q,$ then the equivalence classes are not "convex" but all the other axioms hold.

Comment: @bof Thank you! One last thing - do you have any thoughts about homogeneity? I've thought about it for a while, and I'm pretty sure that the structure homogeneous, but the wording of the question is making me doubt myself.

Comment: Oh, I guess it's homogeneous, why wouldn't it be?

Comment: @bof How would you use $A$ is homogeneous to prove the completeness of the axioms

Comment: I don't know. I would just try to prove that any countable model of my axioms is isomorphic to $\mathcal A.$